# A rectangle of a given aspect ratio inscribed in a hexagon.

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the largest rectangle of a given aspect ratio that can be inscribed in a hexagon.

[image]

I'm able to sort of walk through the problem in reverse, i.e. given an x, I can calculate the rectangle and aspect ratio :

1. find the point on AB for x
2. find the point on DE for x
3. find the point on BC across from #1
4. calculate height : distance between #1 & #2
5. calculate width : distance between #1 & #3
6. Aspect ratio is #5 / #4

How would I go about doing this in reverse?  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: This seems like a max/mim problem of elementary calculus. You need to write the relationship between all of the parts and then use derivative rules to find maximums and minimums. Overall, this seems far more advanced than elementary geometry. How did you come up with this problem?

Comment: I suspected it might be a calculus problem... The reason I'm trying to find the answer is that I'm developing an app that uses hexagons.  Older version of the app : http://www.olympianoiseco.com/apps/chordion/

Comment: In regards to your comment, I didn't retain any of my calculus from when I was in HS, so I'm not totally sure how to approach your suggestion. What do you mean "write the relationship between all the parts?"

Answer (score 2):

Let the aspect ratio be $A=\frac wh$ and take the side of the hexagon as $1$.  Let $d$ be the distance between $AD$ and the side you have labeled $h$.  The distance between $AD$ and $CF$ is $\sqrt 3$, so $w+2d=\sqrt 3$.  If you draw horizontal lines from $A$ and $D$ they will cut off a piece of the side marked $h$ at each end.  The triangles formed are $30-60-90$, so $h=1+2d\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$  I have followed your point labels, but the diagram below does not.

[image]

$$w+2d=\sqrt 3\\h=1+2d\frac 1{\sqrt 3}\\Ah+2d=\sqrt 3
\\A(1+\frac 2{\sqrt 3}d)+2d=\sqrt 3\\A+d(\frac 2{\sqrt 3}A+2)=\sqrt 3
\\d=\frac {\sqrt 3-A}{\frac 2{\sqrt 3}A+2}=\frac{3-\sqrt 3A}{2A+2\sqrt 3}\\
w=\sqrt 3-2\cdot \frac{3-\sqrt 3A}{2A+2\sqrt 3}\\
h=1+\frac 2{\sqrt 3}\cdot \frac{3-\sqrt 3A}{2A+2\sqrt 3} $$